Inquiry Regarding User Logout Functionality for ACC Integration
Based on the current ACC documentation, we haven't found an API that allows us to directly log a user out of ACC. In our implementation, we clear the locally stored tokens when the user logs out from our platform, which allows them to log back in. However, the user remains logged into ACC, and they must manually log out from ACC if they wish to switch accounts.
is there any API that allows the user to logout or to switch accounts
I just clear our tokens but this is not valid for logging out the user

We can log out the Autodesk user account by calling https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/logout or https://accounts.autodesk.com/Authentication/LogOut in an iframe to switch user accounts in the custom apps.
Here is how we implemented in the hub browser tutorial:
import { initViewer, loadModel } from './viewer.js';
import { initTree } from './sidebar.js';

const login = document.getElementById('login');
try {
    const resp = await fetch('/api/auth/profile');
    if (resp.ok) {
        const user = await resp.json();
        login.innerText = `Logout (${user.name})`;
        login.onclick = () => {
            const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            iframe.src = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/logout';
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            iframe.onload = () => {
                window.location.replace('/api/auth/logout'); //!<<< Clear server session in the tutorial sample.
                document.body.removeChild(iframe);
            };
        }
        const viewer = await initViewer(document.getElementById('preview'));
        initTree('#tree', (id) => loadModel(viewer, window.btoa(id).replace(/=/g, '')));
    } else {
        login.innerText = 'Login';
        login.onclick = () => window.location.replace('/api/auth/login');
    }
    login.style.visibility = 'visible';
} catch (err) {
    alert('Could not initialize the application. See console for more details.');
    console.error(err);
}

ref:

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/logout-GET/
https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-hubs-browser-nodejs/blob/develop/wwwroot/main.js

